# Unable to install Android USB driver on Windows 7 Pro 64 bit

Tags: android, installation, usb, driver, windows-7-x64

Unlike some others, my Android SDK setup went smoothly on my new Windows 7 Pro 64 bit machine. However, I am currently hung up on installing the android usb drivers. What is the current state of this issue? There has been some discussion of this problem on the web but no consensus is immediately apparent.

Comment: What's the actual problem? It's stuck? Complaining that the drivers aren't signed? or what?

Comment: Install Either OEM driver or make one by hand as in:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709263/google-android-usb-driver-and-adb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short: downloaded DROID and HTC Hero USB drivers, installed them. Now its all good.

Comment: Where did you download these drivers from?

Answer (score 14):

The [Android USB driver page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) for Windows is very misleading, IMHO.  It doesn't mention that it doesn't work for all Android devices.  It turns out that for certain devices you need to go to the manufacturer's website for the USB drivers, NOT use the generic Android USB driver.

For example, in my case the generic Android USB driver would not work for my Sony Ericsson X10a.  I forget the exact error message, but the Windows Device Manager would not recognize the driver software as being valid for the device.  But after I downloaded the  X10a USB driver from the Sony Ericsson developer website, the Windows Device Manager was happy with it.  Then I was able to install my Android development apps on the device and debug via Eclipse/DDMS.

BTW, I too am using 64-bit Windows 7 (which is not the real source of the problem).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for the question. I followed your advice and downloaded `Samsung Kies` from the vendor's website, which apparently installed the necessary drivers for my Samsung Galaxy S2.

Comment: For HTC phones you usually need to install htc-sync-manager to get the usb drivers:
http://www.htc.com/us/support/software/htc-sync-manager.aspx

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem - with OEM drives and Android SDK drivers too. Finally what helped me was:
Device Manager - Update Drives Software - Browse my computer for driver software - **Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer** - Have Disk - **Browse for file android_winusb.inf (in sdk folder)** - Android ADB

Windows was not able to find drives in folder automatically :-/

I hope it helps to someone...

Comment: Thanks so much. This helped me, except I had a list of `Common hardware types:`, and I needed to click `Show All Devices` before I could click on `HAVE disk` (not hard disk). This saved me from all sorts of wasted hours on the net...

Answer (score 3):

I tried all this solutions but nothing worked. Finally i found that i need to connect my device as camera and not as media device in phone under "USB PC Connection" in settings and i got it worked. But really it is a long struggle... :) For more details, see this link..

http://junefabrics.com/android/driver.php

I hope this will help someone with the same problem.

Comment: Connect as camera, thank you!  In settings: Storage > Upper right button: USB computer connection > Camera (PTP)

Comment: On my phone none of the options were ticked in the USB computer connection settings page. I selected "Media Device (MTP)" and it worked straight away.

Answer (score 2):

Tried this driver from Intel (after checking all kind of drivers (asus, google, samsung kies etc).
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-usb-driver-for-android-devices

and it worked like a charm (after unplugging and replugging the usb from my Nexus 7 and enabling MTP)

Answer (score 1):

The [Android Drivers Installation](http://androiddriver.net/) has download package and installation instruction.

Comment: When I upgraded my Zenithink tablet to Ice Cream Sandwich, USB driver could not be installed automatically. I just followed instructions on the page as you tipped. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed the driver and it doesn't load... you can try this :
In windows 7,

1. Go to Computer Management , then Device Manager
2. Locate your device...
3. Right-click, and Uninstall... (make sure your device is unplugged)
4. Then Reinstall it again. (run the driver setup)

This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=36523572

Try the above link. its an Universal Android USB Driver. Worked on windows 7!

Answer (score 0):

[Softpedia's Galaxy S USB Driver](http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/MOBILES/Samsung/Samsung-Galaxy-S-USB-Driver-for-Windows-x64.shtm) worked on win7 x64 for me. Galaxy S Phones. Vibrant / Captivate

Answer (score 0):

just install the oem [android driver](http://www.androidsim.net/2009/08/how-to-1-how-to-install-usb-driver-on.html). pretty simple to do. unless if they dont have one you have to do it manually.