# Google Android USB Driver and ADB

Tags: android, windows, adb, inf

I am looking for guidance or a definitive answer on the following.  I want to use the Google Android USB Driver and modify the `android_winusb.inf` to support any number of Android devices.  I was able to add an HTC Evo tablet successfully, but when I try to add LG (Optimus) or Samsung (Indulge, Admire) the driver seems to install fine, but ADB does not see it.

Can you make the Google Android Driver work for any Android phone?  If so... how?

I have tried many permutations of `%SingleAdbInterface%` and `%CompositeAdbInterface%` with the variations of Vendor and Product ids.

Comment: Go to the support website for the manufacturer of the device. For the devices with which the generic driver does not work, the manufacturer usually provides a driver for download that will enable ADB.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion yet? If it worked, please +1 and accept as the answer. This will help boost your profile and make people more likely to help you in the future. Thanks

Comment: I am trying to *not* support multiple device drivers.  I have an application that talked to android devices through ADB and I do not want to manage the installation of n drivers.  Nor do I want the user to have to worry about installing multiple drivers.

Comment: I am confused, in your op you said "to support any number of Android devices" but here you are saying "I am trying to not support multiple device drivers". Maybe i am the only one that is confused with your question now, but could please explain it again a little differently. Thanks

Comment: I have an app that I want to talk to any android device through ADB.  I don't want to install multiple drivers but would like to support through the single Google Android ADB Driver.  I was successful in configuring that driver for multiple devices (Nexus, Moto, ADB) through editing the android_winusb.inf.  But unsuccessful with some devices (LG, Samsung).  I would like to understand why the same method for editing the android_winusb.inf did not work for those devices but did for others.

Comment: try my way of making the "truly universal" driver http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-make-truly-universal-adb-and.html

Answer (score 86):

You need to modify 3 things in order to make Google USB driver work for any android phone on any Windows:

1. Add your device's ID to `android_winusb.inf` file
2. Digitally sign the modified driver
3. Add your device's vendor ID to `adb_usb.ini` whitelist (no longer required)

and here are the details:

**1. Add your device's ID to `android_winusb.inf` file**

the format to add is:

```
;Comment usually the device name
%SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\; here you put VID and PID
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\; same as above but add the MI
```

before I go on, `VID` is the USB Vendor ID.

How to get the vid and pid : they are in drivers you are merging; but if you don’t have a driver for the device you can get it by opening device manager; then right-click the device – select properties-in new dialog go to Details tab >in property drop menu select hardware ids. for example you see something like:

[image: MSI Composite ADB Driver Interface Properties]

```
USB\VID_2207&PID_0000&REV_0222&MI_01
USB\VID_2207&PID_0000&MI_01
```

take this value for composite adb device and remove MI for single adb device, you get

```
;MSI WindPad Enjoy 7 plus
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_2207&PID_0000
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_2207&PID_0000&REV_0222&MI_01
;
```

copy this 2 line TWICE , once to  [Google.NTx86] section and another to [Google.NTamd64] section

REPEAT for every device you want to support

Now an optional edit for [Strings] Section: edit

```
[Strings]
ProviderName                = “Google, Inc.”
SingleAdbInterface          = “Android ADB Interface”
CompositeAdbInterface       = “Android Composite ADB Interface”
SingleBootLoaderInterface   = “Android Bootloader Interface”
WinUSB_SvcDesc              = “Android USB Driver”
DISK_NAME                   = “Android WinUsb installation disk”
ClassName                   = “Android Device”
```

To:

```
[Strings]
ProviderName                = “Google, Inc.”
SingleAdbInterface          = “MSI ADB Interface”
CompositeAdbInterface       = “MSI Composite ADB Interface”
SingleBootLoaderInterface   = “MSI Bootloader Interface”
WinUSB_SvcDesc              = “MSI USB Driver”
DISK_NAME                   = “MSI WinUsb installation disk”
ClassName                   = “MSI Tablet”
```

**2. Digitally sign the modified driver:**

Although the original google usb driver was signed by google , modifying android_winusb.inf will prevent installing it on windows 8 showning an error message
[image: hasherror]

```
The hash file is not present in the specified catalog file. The file is likely
corrupt    or the    victim of tampering.
```

This is only in Windows 8. Windows 7 or earlier do not show this error message. You have to regenerate catalog file (probably with Windows SDK) and sign

Workaround: A workaround for internal tesing is to diable windows signature verification : either temporarily or permanently:

temporarily:

Go to left upper or lower corner of screen to open charms bar and click settings charm.

choose Change PC settings

choose General

Scroll down, and click ‘Restart now’ under ‘Advanced startup’.

Click ‘Troubleshoot’.
Click ‘Advanced Options’
Click ‘Windows Startup Settings’
Click Restart.

or

run cmd
and type:

```
shutdown -o -r -t 0
```

then after restarting choose  ‘Disable driver signature enforcement‘  from the list . install your driver before restarting.

Permanently:

press Window+Q

search for cmd

right click cmd

choose run as administrator from action bar

type in cmd:

```
bcdedit -set loadoptions DISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING ON
```

**3. Add your device's vendor ID to `adb_usb.ini` whitelist (no longer required):**

`adb` used to have a hard-coded whitelist of supported Vendor IDs. If your device's vendor was not on the list - the `adb` was ignoring it completely. To make `adb` recognize such devices users had to manually add their vendor IDs to `%USERPROFILE%\.android\adb_usb.ini` - one ID per line.

in the command line:

```
echo 0x2207 >> "%USERPROFILE%\.android\adb_usb.ini"
```

Fortunately, Google has removed the VendorID filtering in more recent `adb` versions. So this step is no longer required.

**Finally you can test installation by :**

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb devices
```

and enabling debugging in developer options on android device

This should restart ADB Server and list devices. If driver is working ok, the device should be listed.

Comment: Thank you so much, it saved lot of my time. I forgot that windows 8 needs to disable the signature before install the device. Happy code

Comment: Kudos for the answer! does anybody have more info about signing drivers on windows? it seems since win10 you need a EV certificate...?

Comment: item#1 is unnecessarily overcomplicated (see http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-make-truly-universal-adb-and.html ) and item#3 is outdated (it was not a bug but a feature anyway) so item#2 was the only useful part

Answer (score 8):

Locate the following file

> `C:\Users\`[your name]`\.android\adb_usb.ini`

And make the following changes:

```
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.
0x2207
```

I added `0x2207` to the file. This number is part of the hardware id, which can be found under the device's hardware information.

Mine was:

`USB\VID_2207&PID_0010&MI_01`

(I tried executing `android update adb`, but it did nothing.)

Answer (score 7):

Can you give us a better description and an example of what you are doing? Because all i have to do is put the line in there for the device and then save the file. Now just reconnect the device and it works.

I usually use something similar to this line:

```
;
;some name for the phone (this seems to be arbitrary)
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, THE_HARDWARE_ID
```

What i do, is:

1. plug the device into the computer.
2. Go to your device manager.
3. Right click on the device that you plugged up.
4. Go to properties. Then select Hardware Ids.
5. Then get that value that is listed there.
6. Now add it to the line you created in the `android_winusb.inf`.
7. Unplug the device and plug back in
8. Go back to the device manager
9. Right click on the device and click update or install driver
10. Select search your computer for the driver
11. Select the directory
     `Your_Android_SDK_Directory/extras/google/usb_driver/`
12. Press ok

That seems to always work for me, is that what you are doing? Or does this even help?

Comment: I have an application that talked to android devices through ADB and I do not want to manage the installation of n drivers. Nor do I want the user to have to worry about installing multiple drivers.

Comment: I tried the method above for the phone I listed and didn't work.  I tried with the HTC Evo and it did.  No luck with Samsung or LG.

Comment: I am not sure what to do beyond this point. This always works for me and i can not re-produce the problem.

Comment: After adding the lines what do you do? Do you restart or do you reconnect the device and it recognizes?

Comment: Works for WideFly Wireless POS PDA (WF360) folks.. Thank you prolink007, i gave you upvote..

Answer (score 2):

1. modify android_winusb.inf
2. Sign the driver
3. modify adb

I also instaled generic adb driver from http://adbdriver.com/
and it works.

Comment: The answer is poor, but the linked universal driver is great, really universal! Likely, it performs the first two operations automatically.

Comment: thank you so much, reference link is sworking for me, +1 for reference link.

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1 worked perfectly for me.  I tested it on a new MID 10' tablet.  Here are the lines I added in the .inf file and it installed without a problem:

```
;Google MID
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_INSTALL, USB\Vid_18d1&Pid_0003&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_INSTALL, USB\Vid_18d1&Pid_0003&Rev_0230&MI_01
```

Comment: What do you do after adding the lines? How does it recognize and install the driver?

Answer (score 1):

For my Azpen A727, the Windows driver installed correctly, so only step 3 of Mohammad's answer was necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the Google USB drivers have been updated to support Glass out of the box, so as long as you use the latest drivers, you should be able to access Glass via ADB. In my particular situation, I had connected Glass to my machine sometime mid-2014 but did nothing with it. Now when I was trying to connect it, I would not see it show up in ADB despite showing up in Device Manager. After much trial and error, I found out that I had to:

1. Go into Device Manager
2. Right click "Android ADB Interface" under "SAMSUNG Android Phone"
3. Click "Uninstall". BE SURE
   "Delete the driver software for this device" is checked.
4. Disconnect and reconnect Google Glass.

I was then able to reinstall the driver via regular Windows update. This forced it to look for the newest driver. Not sure why it was not getting updated before, but I hope this will help someone out there still struggling with this.

Answer (score 1):

Driver for Huawei was not found. So I've been using the universal ADB driver:

- Download [this](http://adbdriver.com/upload/adbdriver.zip):
- Extract `ADBDriverInstaller` and Run the file. Make sure you have connected your device through USB to your computer.
- A window is displayed.
- Click Install.
- A dialog box will appear. It will ask you to press the `Restart` button.

**Before doing that read [this](http://adbdriver.com/documentation/how-to-install-adb-driver-on-windows-8-10-x64.html) link**:

`(The above. in brief, says to press Restart button in the dialog box. Select Troubleshoot. Select Advance Option. Select Startup Setting. Press Restart. After system's been restarted, on the appearing screen press 7)`

- When PC has been Restarted, Run the `ADBDriverInstaller` file again. Select your device from the options. Press install.

And it's done :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of modifying adb_usb.ini file I made changes on the file **android_winusb.inf** under directory android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\  alone and it worked   for the tablet MID Q88 but i copied both sections  [Google.NTamd64] and [Google.NTx86]

```
;Google MID Q88
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_INSTALL, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0003&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_INSTALL, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0003&REV_0230&MI_01
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow. But what is the use of adding an answer which already provided?