# What is SingleAdbInterface, CompositeAdbInterface and SingleBootLoaderInterface in android_winusb.inf

Tags: android, mobile, usb, adt

I have an Android device that I want to use it for development (USB debugging).  Apparently, the `Android Composite ADB Interface` is not supported by ADT's USB driver.

I then try to find it's Hardware ID from Device Manager:

```
USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C03&REV_0255&MI_01
USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C03&MI_01
```

and attempt to add entries in `android_winusb.inf`.  The inf file has something like this:

```
;Google Nexus (generic)
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE0
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE1
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE2
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE2&MI_01
```

How may I define the USB ID into the .inf file?  What is `SingleBootLoaderInterface`, `SingleAdbInterface` and `CompositeAdbInterface` for?

Answer (score 1):

You can define your device like below :

```
; HTC Dream
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C03
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C03&MI_01
```

You can find more explanations in this other question : [Google Android USB Driver and ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709263/google-android-usb-driver-and-adb)