# Moto X doesn't show up in Eclipse Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, driver, windows-8.1, android-sdk-tools

I have a Droid X (4.2.2), in developer mode.

I have Eclipse Juno running on Windows 8.1, with latest Android tools.

When I plug the device, I see "USB debugging connected" on the device, Windows offers me to browse files, but Eclipse's "Devices" tab doesn't show any device at all.

Tried to restart the device and eclipse.

There are no Win8 instructions but I've tried to follow the Win7 instructions: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Win7 but when I browse to the driver folder it says it cannot find the driver.

The link to the Motorola OEM drivers is dead (http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Drivers).

Comment: A detailed answer to get you going is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709263/google-android-usb-driver-and-adb/15609366#15609366 . Additional steps are needed to enable unsigned drivers on Windows 8 after you modify the ".inf" file. See here: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-can-i-install-hardware-with-unsigned-drivers-in-windows-8/

Answer (score 7):

Motorola provides a device manager that installs the proper drivers for you.  My moto x showed up just fine after the install.

https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481/action/auth