# My Android device does not appear in the list of adb devices

Tags: android, adb

I have a HP Slate 21 that is connected to my Windows box using a USB cable.

USB debugging is enabled on the device.

After [adding the proper `%SingleAdbInterface%` and `%CompositeAdbInterface%`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15609366/3063884) entries to the `android_winusb.inf` file, I now see "Android ADB Interface" in my Device Manager.
However, running `adb devices` at the command-line does not show the device.

I have another HP slate 7 that shows up just fine under `adb devices`.

The only difference I see from Device Manager is that the one that works is named "Android Composite ADB Interface" and the other one is named "Android ADB Interface."

There is yet another subtle difference. In the winusb.inf file, for Slate 7 I have two `%CompositeAdbInterface%` entries defined but for Slate 21, there is just one `%CompositeAdbInterface%` entry defined.

How can I see my device by running the command `adb devices`?

Comment: I get this issue often. Having checked the obvious (USB Debugging Enabled) it usually comes down to the cable. Even the official cable isn't always good enough for debugging over USB, as is the case with this Samsung J510 I am trying to debug now. Works for Inspector but does not show up in adb devices.
Swapped cable to one I know works, and I can now see it in adb!

Comment: update your SDK by **adding the version of your Android device** using the SDK manager

Comment: There is a promt screen on phone when you connect to device. If you accept it, this will be the easiest solve

Comment: go to developer options and turn on USB debugging

Comment: setting - general - about device - click build number many time - 
back to general - developer options - tick USB debugging

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Looks like the installed driver was in bad state. Here is what I did to make it work:

1. Delete the device from Device Manager.
2. Rescan for hardware changes.
3. List item "Slate 21" will show up with "Unknown driver" status.
4. Click on "Update Driver" and select /extras/google/usb_driver

Device Manager will find the driver and warn you about installing it. Select "Yes."
This time the device got installed properly.

Note that I didn't have to modify winusb.inf file or update any other driver.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your solution worked for me even today on 20-10-2019 nokia 7.2 :D

Comment: What the heck is "/extras/google/usb_driver" supposed to be? It's not part of adb platform-tools.

Comment: THis works I downloaded my drivers from https://www.driverscape.com/files/misc/Motorola_End_User_Driver_Installation_6.2.0_64bit.zip cos I'm using motorola and update the driver on my device manager . Thanks @peter

Comment: Where is the device Manager?

Answer (score 263):

I had a similar issue and solved with the following steps:

1. Disconnect device, and ensure to turn **off** developer options on the android device (if was previously turned on).
2. Connect the device via USB.
3. Turn on developer options on the android device.
4. Enable check box for stay awake.
5. Enable check box for USB debugging.
6. Open `cmd` (or MacOS' console), and `cd` where your `adb` executable is.

   > Should be in SDK's `platform-tools`, which you can get from official-site: https://developer.android.com/studio.
7. Finally, run the commands:

   ```
   adb kill-server
   adb start-server
   adb devices
   ```

Now we can see attached devices.

> **Note** that by following above steps, in most cases the USB-connection mode will be automatically set to `MTP` (Media Transfer Prorocol), but try setting that manually if it does not happen automatically.
>
> Also, if above-steps do not work for you, try purchasing a new USB-cable, then retry above-steps (with the "new USB-cable").

### More Debugging (Wireless)

If it still not working and you wish to try wirelessly.

1. Remove the USB
2. Put your smartphone on flight mode
3. Disconnect your laptop from the WiFi.
4. Reconnect both *(on the same WiFi)*
5. Android: Go under "Wireless debugging" > "Pair device with pairing code"
6. CLI: `adb pair [ip]:[port]` *(with element found on "5.")*
7. CLI: Enter the pairing code
8. Android: Close the pairing screen & look at the "IP address and port
9. CLI: `adb connect [ip]:[port]` *(With element found on "8.")*

Comment: Enable USB debugging was probably the key. This is what worked for me.

Comment: I've checked and unchecked `Stay awake`, and it helped in my case.

Comment: I had a bad cable. Changing cables worked.

Comment: I did it as written, but no success. List of devices attached, empty

Comment: 7, start-server is not necessary, will start if not yet started.

Comment: What does step 5 mean?

Comment: Also resolved for me by revoking all debugging authorisations and Android Debug Options, and confirming it again for my computer.

Comment: I needed one more step:  Unplug the device and plug it back in.  Thanks!

Comment: My Pixel needed to be above 15% battery to be recognised. Also I did do `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server`

Comment: After trying multiple times this gymnastic, I had to reboot my Ubuntu 22.04. Then it worked... gezzz

Comment: Don't use cheap cables. In my case, I had to use a decent cable.

Comment: Some micro-usb cables are charging-only and no data transfer is possible.

Answer (score 221):

Make sure your device is not connected as a media device.

Comment: Can confirm that this is critical!   On Android 5.0, go to Settings -> Storage -> menu -> USB computer connection and make sure 'Media device (MTP)' is disabled.  When it's disabled 'adb devices' lists the device, when enabled not.  Tried with both Nexus 4 and Nexus 5.

Comment: going from MTP to "charging" wasn't enough for me, I had to go all the way and say "PTP" for the connection.

Comment: Android Nougat: Settings -> Developer options -> Networking -> Select USB Configuration.  Changing it to MTP worked for me.

Comment: For me It worked after Selecting "MIDI" Option

Comment: For me, in Android 7.1.1, I had to change the USB connection from "File transfer" to "Photo transfer".  Thanks for this answer, though.

Comment: I will also note, though, that I had to change it BACK to "File transfer" mode before Android Studio would run code on my device.  I also needed to adjust my udev rules (added my specific device), and ensure the Linux user running Android Studio was in the plugdev group (Gentoo).  At that point, I was prompted to allow debugging from the connected computer.

Comment: I couldn't find Developer options. It turned out that you need to click multiple times on "Kernel" field in About section to turn on the Developer Options. (it's for security)

Comment: For me MTP didn't work, but PTP did work, although not from the first time, I was also killing and restarting ADB a couple of times, plugged to different USB, toggled off/on USB  debugging, revoked USB debugging authorizations, enabled Stay Awake, so I tried all I could, and then after switching to PTP one more time the phone finally showed a question to allow my laptop for debugging.

Comment: On my phone with Android 8.0, I enabled the "USB debugging" and the device was listed in the devices list (tip for linux users: use the "watch -n1 adb devices" command, in order to catch the "real time" update of devices list). Choose PTP or MTP was indifferent for me. The device was listed anyway.

Comment: I also have to select `Enable view attribute inspection`.

Comment: How do I set this setting with an Oculus Go?

Comment: Android 9 here: Go to `Settings` -> `Developer options` -> and then change `Default USB configuration`

Comment: you will not believe, there is one more solution: If all these solutions doesn't work, you might have issue in usb cable you would be using. I had used a bluetooth speaker's cable, that doesn't support usb debugging. So beware of cable. Use only the phone's cable.

Comment: for certain devices - 'Transfer Files' option does the job

Comment: Android 10 here. I just select MIDI then boom, it's now connected. Thanks

Comment: After trying lots of things I got mine to work by connecting with the wireless adb command `adb connect 192.168.0.x`. Once my computer registered the device over the wireless network it didn't seem to have any issues connecting with USB.

Comment: On a OP9 Pro: `Developer Options > Select USB Configuration > PTP (Picture transfer protocol)`

Comment: @sffc, Azhar, Pistos, HenrikB, zubko. Regardless of all those settings, are you guys sure that toggling USB Debugging was not all that was needed?

Answer (score 63):

In *Android 8 Oreo*:

1. go into Settings / Developer Options / Select USB Configuration;
2. Select **PTP (Picture Transfer Protocol)**.

Comment: Also the same in Android 5, USB PC connection has to be **PTP** or `adb devices -l` will not show the phone.

Comment: MTP isn't good?

Comment: They renamed it to Transfer Images, this worked for me.

Comment: What if you cannot access the phone's UI?

Answer (score 47):

For me the solution was to use a different USB port on my laptop

Comment: I had a usb-c -> 4x usb-a hub on my mac which didn't work but the usb-a on the mac adapter dongle worked.

Comment: My original Samsung's cable was a little bit broken and I changed it and worked

Answer (score 46):

While many of these solutions have worked for me in the past, they all failed me today on a Mac with a Samsung S7. After trying a few cables, someone suggested that the ADB connection requires an official Samsung cable to work. Indeed, when I used the Samsung cable, ADB worked just fine. I hope this helps someone else!

Comment: I doubted this. Changing cable worked. Gosh darnit Samsung.

Comment: What is special about a Samsung USB cable?  How could the phone or computer recognize it?

Comment: This was the closest answer for me. The new cable was not official either, the old one was just damaged. It worked for charging and file transfer, but seems that it was not enough for remote debuggery.

Comment: Wow changing the cable, plus the answer of @Marco Lackovic to use PTP solved it for me,as both were needed.

Comment: Same here! I've been working with Xamarin Android on many devices, but today, to install an app on my mother Samsung S8, I had to use the official cable.

Comment: It's 2022 and I can confirm that this works for me. Silly Samsung.

Answer (score 31):

Disable and re-enable "use debug mode" on your telephone

Comment: Yes, this worked for me too. Just went to Settings -> Developer Options (if this is not available on your phone you need to enable it by following below steps) -> Tick 'Use Debugging' and 'Stay awake'                                                                   
                                                                                                                 To enable Developer Options go to Settings -> About Device -> Keep tapping on 'Build number' until message will appear saying 'Developer Options have been enabled'.

Comment: Thanks a lot, after trying all answers above finally tried yours answer and got solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 28):

In Galaxy s6 - I resolved it by: Settings -> About device -> Software info -> Build number - tap it 7 times to enable Developer options. Go back to Settings -> Developer options -> turn on USB debugging.

Go back to your terminal `adb devices` and you should see the connected device. Hope that helps.

Comment: The part about tapping settings > about > build fixed my lack of dev support on a yuntab.  Thanks!

Comment: I tried all these steps but still 'adb devices'can't find my device.  any other thing we need to consider? I am on windows 10

Comment: I am using onePlus and same steps settings -> about phone -> build number - tap 7 times. Then go to settings -> developer options -> turn on usb debugging and showed my my device on adb devices  tada

Comment: I also had to change to use `PTP` usb connection after I tapped 7 times and enabled USB debugging. On a Google Pixel3A, fwiw

Comment: This fixed it!!

Answer (score 22):

I tried everything on this thread but nothing worked. My problem: my computer was charging the device when I was connecting the cable on, so I assumed the cable was working, but not. After I swap the cable, `adb devices` worked. The cable was the issue.

Comment: I reinstalled drivers, tried different options but no success. Finally I changed the cable and it worked! Later I found out that cable was from device that hadn't been supposed to be connected to PC only charging!

Answer (score 20):

I also had same problem, i tried to use all the possible solution posted on this thread, but i found out i had same problem as **JohnnyFun** explained, but as per **HenrikB** solution i could not find any settings option in my Samsung Galaxy S6 phone ( Android 6.0.1)

Settings -> Storage -> menu -> USB computer connection

I finally figure - when connecting my phone throught charger in pull down menu i see options like -

[image]

Then click on "Connected for chargin " >>> you will see options like >>

[image]

Over there you can change option to "Transferring media type files"

Comment: Now I need to figure out how to do this when the phone's screen is damaged and won't accept any touch inputs.

Comment: For my device, Android 9, "Charging" option was the USB connection way that works.

Answer (score 17):

On Android 7.1 Nougat (in my case, a Moto G), manually re-enabling USB debugging on [Developer Options](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options.html) did the trick:

`Settings > Developer Options > USB debugging`

[image]

```
PS C:\> adb devices
List of devices attached
myDeviceNumber      device
```

Comment: Everyone assumes that you haven't enabled debugging when you ask this question, but in my case I had.  I think the problem might have been that I had never attached this android device to my existing laptop (I had previously debugged on a different laptop).  Turning off usb debugging and then plugging the device back in totally solved it.

Answer (score 16):

Tried off/on developer/usb options, but turns out swopping for another cable worked. Just in case someone waste time trying everything software.

Comment: how is this different from 3 other answers on this page recommending to replace the cable?

Answer (score 14):

Turning on tethering actually allowed me to install and debug on a LG device and it was the only way it would work

Comment: I use a tablet, no tethering, this can be the problem why it does not work.

Answer (score 13):

Have you ever reset the adb after you installed the new device?

[image]

Or from command line:

1. Close Eclipse if running
2. Go to the Android SDK platform-tools directory in Command Prompt (ok, you knew this, i know!)
3. type `adb kill-server`
4. then type `adb start-server`
5. Read if there are some errors otherwise try `adb devices` again

Answer (score 12):

After trying all the solutions and still not finding a solution, I deduced the problem to the USB cable(s).

Since it was working sometimes for me (ie at work) and not other times (ie at home), I decided to try out different cables and different Android phones I had. And sure enough, some of the cables did not work (adb can't see phone) with any of the phones, but they still charged the phone and Android recognized that it was plugged in.

The good cables obviously charged the phones and were immediately recognized by adb. It was a pretty clear difference.

I couldn't tell the cables apart physically from outside, but all were free USB cables I've gathered over the years.

Comment: Same with me. Worth trying if you're out of ideas. I used an Xbox One controller charge cable in the end.

Answer (score 7):

**just try** `adb kill-server` **then**

```
adb devices
```

Comment: Kindly Comment if doesn't work.

Comment: doesn't work dude

Comment: Did not work for me.

Comment: @EliezerMiron what error you getting ?

Comment: No error, the adb interface relaunched just fine. It turns out I just needed to reboot my system after installing the ADB drivers.

Comment: Thats Great ! Sounds Good (Y)

Answer (score 7):

So the methods mentioned above didn't work for me. What worked for me was googling Samsung Galaxy Tab USB driver and downloading and running the application that got my device recognized when I did adb devices. Since I was using a Samsung Galaxy, I used this link to download the usb driver from the OFFICIAL Samsung site. You would want to google your own respective android model usb driver

http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I925EAAVZW

After downloading it, I ran the application to install my usb driver and then did adb devices. Make sure your Google USB driver from the Android SDK is downloaded and that your sdk is up to date as well. Also, make sure that your USB debugging mode is enable by going to Settings -> Developer Options -> then checking USB debugging. After all this, your device in the Device Manager should not have a yellow exclamation point next to it. When you run adb devices your device should show up. Hope this helps people. I literally spent hours trying to figure this out. Hopefully my answer could save you guys the hours I spent googling.

Comment: LOL. What worked for me was changing my data cable..!

Answer (score 7):

Toggling USB debugging off and then back on did the trick for me.

Answer (score 6):

For WINDOWS users, Follow the instruction here.
[https://help.esper.io/hc/en-us/articles/12657625935761-Installing-the-Android-Debug-Bridge-ADB-Tool#:~:text=Installing%20ADB%20on%20Windows,-Windows%20Mac&text=Step%201%3A%20Download%20and%20install,Android%20SDK%20Command%2DLine%20tools](https://help.esper.io/hc/en-us/articles/12657625935761-Installing-the-Android-Debug-Bridge-ADB-Tool#:%7E:text=Installing%20ADB%20on%20Windows,-Windows%20Mac&text=Step%201%3A%20Download%20and%20install,Android%20SDK%20Command%2DLine%20tools)

Basically, MTP/PTP all is not needed. You need to configure your device from device manager by following the instruction in screenshots of the page.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Jolly, this is the correct answer!
I tried everything and nothing worked except installing this driver!
Thank you!

Comment: Link is 404, please update or remove.

Answer (score 4):

adb was not detecting connected nexus 5 device.
Switched on the phone, enabled developer options, Enabled USB debugging mode, Now visible with adb. Also, USB configuration is still MTP. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

I have an Android LG G4 and the only thing that worked for me was to install the Software Update and Repair tool from my device.  Steps:

- Plug device into usb
- Make sure developer options are enabled and usb
  debugging is checked (see elsewhere in thread or google for
  instructions)
- Select usb connection type "Software installation":

### [image]

- An installation wizard should come up on the computer.
- At some point during the installation you will see on your phone a prompt that asks "Trust this computer?" with an RSA token/fingerprint.  After you say yes the device should be recognized by ADB and you can finish the wizard.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem with my "Xiaomi Redmi Note 4" and tried almost 10 solutions I found over internet, but none of them helped my case. I've posted this answer to help someones like myself.

Installing "Intel USB Driver for Android Devices" totally solved my problem. It's described completely [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/installing-android-debug-bridge-adb-usb-driver-on-windows).

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me with a Xiaomi Redmi 5A, but the referenced link changed, I found the download link here: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-usb-driver-for-android-devices.html

Answer (score 2):

Same as other android devices, a new Yuntab also requires going to settings > about and tapping on the build number to enable developer status.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this happens because of many reasons depending on your set up, my particular case:

- MacOS Ventura 13.3
- Samsung s23
- Connected via original phone cable to
  original Apple usb Dongle (USB to USB c)

Steps:

1. Go to Android Studio and select "Trouble shoot device connections"
   [image]
2. You will see that the device recognised the dongle but not the phone itself
3. disconnect dongle
4. re-connect dongle with phone connected and click on "rescan devices", it will likely already identify the phone but say that it is waiting for user to authorise USB debugging (even if it is supposed to be on already) [image]
5. go to Developer settings on the phone and turn USB Debugging off and on
6. Phone will now ask you to allow this particular computer for USB debugging
   [image]

enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I had problems getting the ADB driver installed from my Windows7 machine. Turned out the Virusscan "access protection" prevented (only some) drivers to be installed properly. Unplugged USB, uninstalled the samsung device from device manager, disabled VS access protection, plugged usb back in and everything was OK. Wasted an hour, hopes it saves you one.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the options in the answers above

- switch debug mode off    and on
- made USB config - charging
- made stay awake

None worked . For my samsung J7 mobile 
downloaded the [USB driver](https://freeandroidroot.com/download-samsung-usb-drivers) 
post installation , device started showing in adb devices.

Answer (score 1):

Click on Attach Debuger to Android Process and Click On Restart ADB.

Answer (score 1):

for me the solution was to install de driver from sdk manager:

http://visualgdb.com/KB/usbdebug-manual/

Answer (score 0):

In your windows configuration, go to device management. Check if you see your device and if the drivers are installed. You probably do not have the correct drivers installed for your device.

Answer (score 0):

Remove battery from phone, wait 10s, re-add it and try it again (alongside developer options etc.. in other questions)

I tried all other answers, but that was required in addition to the other suggestions for me.

Answer (score 0):

- Pull down the Notifications Bar.
- Tap the item (for example "File transfer") that has the small text "Tap to change USB options" at the bottom.
- Tap "Charging"
- Tap "Just once" or "Always", depending on what you prefer. If you're unsure, tap "Just once".
- Tap "OK".

Note: Before these steps, I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28211161/5231110), but that didn't help and I doubt that those steps were necessary for my solution.

Answer (score -1):

After trying all these steps I needed to run: `adb connect <device IP>:5555` to connect to the device.

After running this command a prompt on my tablet popped up confirming I wanted to allow the connection. Then I was able to see my device when running `adb devices`

For those curious I am using an Elo tablet.

Answer (score -2):

Switching cables worked for me...

Answer (score -3):

I was having same problem in my ubuntu. When I run command `adb devices` it shows me `?????????? No permission`.

Then I tried with `adb kill-server` and then `sudo su` and `adb devices`. No need to run command `adb start-server` devices command will start it automatically if it is not already started.

Hope this will save once one's minutes.

Answer (score -5):

Try to update the **ADB** and the **phone** itself.
Then if it still doesn't work try to 
connect the phone with then without **usb debugging**, 
or with then without **usb storage on**.