# How to connect via USB debugging for Hannspad tablet 10.1" (HSG1279)

Tags: android, adb, usb-debugging

I am having issues with connecting my Hannspad tablet 10.1" (HSG1279) with my pc for USB debugging. When I run `adb devices` in cmd, it doesn't recognise the device.

I have tried:

- Installing Universal ADB Driver
- Installed a number of recommended drivers over the internet
- Running "Windows Update" for driver update
- Tried to connect to the device via wireless (adb Wireless)

**None** of the options above worked for me. I have already spent 1 day trying to figure this out.

Can you please help me?

Thanks

**EDIT**
I have also added my USB VendorID in .android\adb_usb.ini and restarted my adb

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/adb-device-detection-in-windows.html

Comment: Hey Alex thank you for you comment, that didn't work for me! I can detect the device using the second command provided in the post, but still cannot get the adb to recognise the device!

Comment: If it not connecting to PC then you have to search for specific device driver from device manufacturer. If it is not recognizing in the ADB only then follow following link.

Comment: Have you enabled developer options?

Comment: the point of the article was to add your device's USB VendorID to both `%USERPROFILE%\.android\adb_usb.ini` and `%ANDROID_SDK_HOME%\.android\adb_usb.ini` and then restarting `adb` with `adb kill-server` or otherwise. are you sure you have done that?

Comment: yes i have added that in adb_usb.ini and restarted my adb ...

Answer (score -1):

If it not connecting to PC then you have to search for specific device driver from device manufacturer. If it is not recognizing in the ADB only then follow following link .

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/213874/how-to-configure-adb-access-for-android-devices
>
> [Android device does not show up in adb list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170392/android-device-does-not-show-up-in-adb-list)

Comment: Thank you Chavan for your suggestion, unfortunately that didn't work for me either.