# Development on Nexus 5x which cannot connect via USB

Tags: android, nexus-5x

I faced an issue with my Nexus 5x which I just acquired for Android 8 development: even after setting the development mode to be on, USB debugging to be on, Android Studio or adb refused to see it. (On the other hand, my Nexus 6 works fine...) Tried a few USB-C wires (including one that said compatible with Nexus 5x). and the result is the same.

I am using a Mac.

1) Is this a hardware defect or is it a USB mode I need to set?
2) If it is not possible to connect, how do I do wireless development (without connecting via wire first)?

Comment: Which OS, Mac or Windows? Install device drivers from here: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb

Comment: Also have you made sure that you have specific drivers installed for nexus 5x ?.

Comment: Hi thanks! Forgot to mentioned that I use a Mac, which should not have driver issue?

Comment: well if you are using mac then you don't even need to install the drivers in the first place. I believe the problem is in your hardware. 
and for the second part, you can set up wireless connection, using tcp, bluetooth or wifi or after rooting your phone :)

Comment: @LimThyeChean and one more thing did you checked in adb if your device is connect, because it happens sometimes that device is connected but it doesn't show on available devices in android studio.

Comment: I also believe it is hardware issue. But then how do you start development without first using the USB cable to connect?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to check if your device is showing in `adc command shell` using this `command`: `adb devices`

if you device is showing then it's good and if not you need to make sure that `Media device (MTP)` is disabled. When it's disabled `adb devices` lists the device, when enabled it does not. After that go through the following process

- Run adb tcpip 5555
- Disconnect your device (remove the USB cable).
- Go to the Settings -> About phone -> Status to view the IP address of
  your phone.
- Run adb connect :5555

more you can follow up with this [Link](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-debug-your-android-app-over-wifi-without-root).

And the **second option** is open your android studio go to

```
file -> settings -> plugins -> search adb wifi
```

install that plugin and follow the steps. More you can read about adb wifi is here:

[Android Wifi ADB](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7983-android-wifi-adb)

[Github link](https://github.com/pedrovgs/AndroidWiFiADB)

Comment: Also take a look at this question too, it's similar to what you are facing right now:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170392/android-device-does-not-show-up-in-adb-list