# Redmi note 6 pro device not access in android studio for debuging

Tags: debugging, device, device-detection

I am trying to debug application on Redmi note 6 pro but i can't debug on this device, i already follow all path and method for troubleshoot for deducting in android studio.Its orignal device and brought from orignal site of Mi.com.

kindly help me out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android device does not show up in adb list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170392/android-device-does-not-show-up-in-adb-list)

Comment: @WaynePhipps,thanks bro. I brought this phone from original site of MI.com so i thing its not duplicate and other devices also brought from this site like Redmi note 5 pro, 5 Pro was showing in adb list but its not (6 pro).

Answer (score 2):

I found the good solution,
If you use Redmi note 6 pro or Redmi Note series then follow steps
1: you should enable developer options:- Settings>About Phone>MIUI version click 7 times frequently,
2:unable USB debugging option, no need to  turn off MIUI OPTIMIZATION.
3:when you connect device with system then choose File transfer option,
now you connected.

if not then unable USB debugging(Security settings) too.