# Xamarin Forms/ Visual Studio building on Android tablet

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to build a Xamarin Forms project onto an Android tablet (Lenovo). The tablet is fully up to date with Android 10. The problem being that on Visual Studio, the tablet doesn't appear as a build option like an Android phone does.

Is it possible to build on a tablet? I can't find anything in the documentation.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried attaching a phone, to make sure the issue is the tablet? Have you made sure the tablet is in developer mode, etc (just like you have to do when debugging to a phone.)

Comment: @conanmcelduff From [Android Tablets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/tablet#android-tablets), we can see that Android ecosystem has a myriad of supported screen sizes, from small phones up to large tablets. Xamarin.Forms can support all screen sizes, but as with the other platforms you might want to adjust your user interface for larger devices.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yeah the phone works perfectly! Tablet is in dev mode with debug on. Just not showing up as a build option.

Comment: ok. First check at a lower level - Tools > Android > Android ADB Command Prompt. See [Android device does not show in adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170392/android-device-does-not-show-up-in-adb-list) for suggestions to try.

Comment: Has your project has set its [maxSdkVersion](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element#max) to a level lower than your device's SDK level? Android 10 is SDK level 29.