# eclipse can't see my lenovo S650 phone

Tags: java, android, eclipse

this is the first time I try to run application on my android phone, but eclipse can't see my phone I'm using lenovo S650. made search and found this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) it said I have to install OEM usb driver from this [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html), this second page said to choose my device OEM driver from the list. and when I select lenovo link, it redirects me to chines page and I can't understand a word in it. is there any resource to get OEM driver from?
OR can any one help me to get eclipse see my phone?
any help will be appreciated, thanx in advance

Comment: You need to edit android_winusb.inf. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15609366) are the details.

Comment: I would check my cable. Then install the proper USB driver and enable the Debug Options on my device.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help solve your problem, but you can download the driver from [here](http://pan.baidu.com/share/link?shareid=579354&uk=3778350703). Click this button to start:

[image]

Comment: I downloaded it but widows always stops the installation and prevents it :(

Answer (score 0):

LePhone doesn't work for me, but...

Try Driver Installer from [here](http://adbdriver.com/downloads/).

It works for my Lenovo A820. Only start installer and choose device, then click on install and it is done.