# Installing Moto X 2nd Gen Debug Driver

Tags: android, windows, usb, driver, motorola

I have a **Windows 7 x64 Ultimate** computer and I want to connect my **Moto X 2nd Gen (XT1097)** in debug mode so I can develop some apps.

The problem is, Windows can't find the drivers for my Moto X. I have downloaded [Motorola Device Manager](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481) (version 2.4.5) which is supposed to have all the drivers but still my Windows can't find the driver. And before anyone asks, yes, I do have debug enabled in the settings of my phone.

So here comes the funny part..... I have tried this same thing with another Win7x64 Ultimate real machine and a Virtual Machine (running inside my own PC). At first Windows couldn't install the debug drivers...but then after I download the **Motorola Device Manager** it installed the debug drivers and I was able to use the phone for development.

The weird thing is, when I connect my phone into my PC, it installs all the media drivers but not the debug ones and this is how my phone is listed under my Window's **Device Manager**:

[image: XT1097 device]

**BUT** in all the other two computers (in which the drivers were successfully installed), this is how my phone is listed, before I install the Motorola Device Manager (which contains all the drivers):

[image: ADB Interface device]

And this is how it's listed after the driver's installation:

[image]

So, in order to try to fix this, I tried to force a driver installation. I found the driver myself under "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Motorola Shared\Mobile Drivers\Drivers" and inside `motoandroid2.inf` I could find a driver called "Motorola ADB Interface" and even my phone's VID/PID was inside this same driver's file!......**BUT it didn't work!**

I still can't use this phone in debug mode, I can't make Android studio see when it's connected, and I also tried to change Google's default driver `android_winusb.inf` including my phone in there, [using this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709263/google-android-usb-driver-and-adb), but again nothing happens.

Does anyone has any clues of what is going on? I am lost, and honestly I don't want to format my PC just because of this.

Comment: I've got the exact same problem. Still no workaround found. I'll try in my other Windows 7 machine... It if works, I'll switch development to that machine even though it is slower (it's a laptop...)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the extremely buggy usb drivers, I would use wireless adb.

On your phone, go to Settings >> Developer options >> ADB over network, and check it.

Then on your computer, to access ADB, type the command `adb connect ip_address` where `ip_address` is the ip address listed in Developer options.

Make sure you allow the ADB shell firewall access.

Comment: That's an interesting workaround...but I can't find these `ADB over network` option on my phone...does it have to be rooted?

Comment: Also, all the references I find for the `ADB over network` states that or the device has to be rooted OR the device has to be connected first over the USB, which is exactly my current problem haha

Answer (score 1):

Even I was suffering from same problem. I am not sure but this problem is occuring while we use **64 bit** OS. I tried the same setting on **32 bit** windows 7 and it is working fine.

**And One important thing...**

Even if we have can see the driver problem in device manager, the device debugging mode is working perfectly fine. I tried chrome inspect element feature and compiled application from ecllipse.

Comment: Installing another OS, even on VM, seems to be not the best possible solution

Comment: Did you solved this on x64? Or did you just moved to a x86 (32 bits) ?

Comment: I tried in another x64 and a VM with a x64 as I said in my first post, and I didn't have any problems, I am not sure x64 is the problem

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame I'm a bit late, but here it goes:

I had the same problem with my moto g 2nd gen and solved it by installing the drivers manually:

1. Download [android SDK zip](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/sdk/index.html#Other).
2. Unzip to *\android-sdk-windows and run sdkmanager.exe .
3. Mark only "usb drivers" or similar (it will also install dependencies).
4. Install.
5. Use device manager to "update driver" manually, choosing to select the .inf file in *\android-sdk-windows\extras\google\usb_driver.

[Here](http://donandroid.com/how-to-install-adb-interface-drivers-windows-7-xp-vista-623) is a more detailed post about it.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to Install**

> [image] Motorola Device Manager

*Let me give the direct links*
http://storage.googleapis.com/tetheredupgrades/MotorolaDeviceManager_2.5.4.exe

https://motorola-global-portal-pt.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/89879

Hope this Helps you.

Answer (score -1):

I  installed motorola drivers at
https://motorola-global-portal-pt.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/89879

It solved my problem on windows 10.

Comment: Good it worked for you, but I said in my question that this didn't worked for me, so this can't be a valid answer for my question.