# I do not see Android tablet in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a cheap DOPO model EM63 tablet that I would like to play around with in Android Studio.  I put the device in developer mode and I made sure enable usb debugging was enabled.  When I plug the device in, It does not appear in Android Studio.  I plugged in my phone and enabled debugging and I can see the phone.  Do I need to download a driver?  What steps should I take to resolve my issue ?

I am running Windows 8.1 on the laptop.  The Android has 4.2.2.

Comment: Which OS (Win 7/8, Mac, Linux) are you running?

Comment: You need to provide more information. What OS is this on? What is the output of running "adb devices"?

Comment: look first answer here for windows 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709263/google-android-usb-driver-and-adb

Comment: Trevor - I edited my question showing the OS.  I'm not sure what you mean by output of running "adb devices".

Comment: `adb` is a tool used by both Android Studio and Eclipse to "see" the connected devices. You need to make sure that `adb` "sees" your device first. http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/adb-device-detection-in-windows.html

Comment: Thanks Alex P.  I am will try using the adb tool.

Comment: Alex - adb does not see my tablet.  Suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

install kies from here:
http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/

its working for me.