# Lenovo USB driver

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, adb, mtp

### Problem:

My smartphone model (Lenovo Vibe B) doesn't have a official driver listed in the OEM USB Driver List (it has for Vibe C and other, I've tried the one for C, because phones are kind of similar but didn't work), so I can't use it in Android Studio to test my apps.

### What I've tried

So my ADB is not recognized or, when I installed an ADB that was found on Device Manager, I got the error Code 10. Updated the drivers, reinstalled all USB drivers, ADB drivers, tried different software like LeTools, LenovoSmartAssistant, MagicPlus, something in chinese, an universal ADB from a developer named Koushik.

Tried different youtube tutorials... also read articles and tried them:[android won't connect](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/android-wont-connect-windows-adb-fix-it-three-steps/), [installing adb driver - lenovo](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-Tablets/Installing-Lenovo-adb-driver-win7-x64/td-p/581095), [how to fix code error 10](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-fix-code-10-errors-2623181)

Also checked official documentation from Google,switched from MTP to PTP** and back to MTP,tried even MIDI

Still my device isn't visible in Android Studio and in Device Manacer is marked with an exclamation sign, or now it's not visible at all.

I mention that I also accept a solution in which I can install my app created on Android studio on the phone and test it without Android Studio. I need to do that because I'll work on an app that requires to be tested few month's, in order to have a database to predict a future behaviour.

Thank you in advance for your help provided!

Comment: Just make sure you are using a USB cable that works with data (i.e. if you can copy pictures off phone, that is good).

Comment: Just found another solution by disabling signature and modifying a .inf file like here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709263/google-android-usb-driver-and-adb?rq=1) Currently trying this, but I've also checked the cable, I've used it before with another phone to debug apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Android Development using the real device you need a tool called Wondershare MobileGo. Its a pcsuit app for Android and ios.

I am using it for 2 years and its the only final solution for all ADB related issues.It contains all type of ADB drivers of android devices currently on market.
You only have to use it once to get the ADB driver installed according to your device model and you can remove it from your pc after that.

Comment: Cool tool, I've been giving it a try, though I've solved my problem already with the solution described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709263/google-android-usb-driver-and-adb?rq=1). Anyway your idea works nice too!