# How to use adb on Windows 8.1 guest (VirtualBox)

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, virtualbox, virtualization

I'm trying to use Android Debug Bridge (adb) from my Windows 8.1 guest (I'm using VirtualBox). The host runs Windows 10.

My enviroment is:

- Guest : Windows 8.1
- Host : Windows 10

I installed the `virtualbox extension pack`, in order to enable the `USB controller 2.0 (EHCI)`.
I also installed `Android Studio` (and `Google USB driver`) on the VM and enable the `"Debug USB"` option on my mobile phone.

When I connect my mobile (via USB), it is recognized by the VM (after selecting it from `Devices -> USB -> MyMobile` menu, I can access to the mobile folders), but when running `adb devices` the device is not listed.
How can use `adb` on my Windows VM guest? Am I missing something?

Comment: Is `Google USB driver` support Your device?

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko Hi, my device is an LG G2 mini

Comment: Check if its PID and VID is in `Google USB driver` `.inf` file. If not - just add them.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko Many thanks. I followed the instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709263/google-android-usb-driver-and-adb) . I added the PID and VID in the `.inf` file, and then reinstalled the driver, but nothing changed. I've repetead the same steps on other mobile (Huawei) and your advice works perfectly. Also I noticed that when plug the LG G2 mini the first time, I found the device under `Device Manager -> Portable Devices -> G2mini`, instead the Huawei under `Device Manager -> Other Devices -> HuaweiPhone` (I'm always in the VM)

Comment: Hmmm... Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20867356/6950238) question or try [that](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54806/lg-g2-debugging-mode-not-enabled) after modifying `inf` file. Or may be You need to install original LG drivers for G2 mini...

Comment: Great. I simply changed the "USB connection method" to PTP, and then repeat all the steps. Now it works like a charm! Many thanks.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first add `PID` and `VID` of Your G2mini phone to `Google USB driver` `.inf` file, then change on Your phone "USB connection method" to PTP as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20867630/6950238) answer of [selbie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104458/selbie).