# PT7003 Tousei Android device not detecting in my Android Studio and ADB

Tags: android, android-studio, driver

I am using Windows 8, my android IDE (Android Studio) does not detecting this Tousei-PT7003-device ,I enabled the developer options and USB Debugging in the device yet the device is not detecting in the Android studio or from the ADB .
Please help me a way to detect this device in my Android studio.I googled and tried many options, yet I am not able to find the correct driver for this Tousei-PT7003 device.

I installed GOOGLE USB Driver also and tried to update the driver but failed with below message:

[image]

When I check the device manager below is the message I can see:

[image]

This is the android device:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/installing-android-debug-bridge-adb-usb-driver-on-windows)?

Comment: yes I tried that already .

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/adb-device-detection-in-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

Solved Driver issue problems for PT7003 Tousei driver,: Issue was driver not installing properly/correctly in Windows 8 OS 
  - followed these  steps and two links:
First download and  install google usb driver from android studio :
 (My driver location:) 
D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver  -point this location when updating the driver.

Modify android_winusb.inf file by the following these steps :

[Google Android USB Driver and ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709263/google-android-usb-driver-and-adb)

Now to ‘Disable driver signature enforcement‘ 
do the following steps from the link:

https://www.dinolite.us/support/using-older-models-with-windows-8-10